# How to sum work-time in excel dynamically?

Tags: java, mysql, excel

Is there a way to write excel formula that is going to sum the total work-hours of specific person? I'd like after John Doe to add another row which is going to be named total: (summed hours), the same for Presley, the same for Jackson. **But** that is not a problem. What if in future I import data from a database and say under the work-hrs column I have something like $(workReport.workHrs), the cell F7 won't be reserved for John Doe's summed work-hours. Maybe in future John Doe will appear 15 times, then his total cell should be F19? [THE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2F88M.jpg)

Comment: Would it be ok to change the range to a table (with headers) ?  Then have this table linked to a pivot table so it dynamically updates?  Or of course use the Sumif as PeterT mentioned below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `SUMIF` function:

```
=SUMIF(B3:B20,"John Doe",F3:F20)
```